# Checking windows file permissions

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm trying to figure out how to check if a directory can be changed to without actually changing to the directory.

On a posix system I would do:

```
if (access("/some/path", X_OK) == 0) {
  // okay!
}
```

If only Windows was so simple ....

I've taken a look at the documentation or `GetFileSecurity`, but I can't seem to wrap my head around Windows ACLs and what I actually have to check for to ensure a directory can be changed to.

Comment: Try '_access'. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1w06ktdy.aspx

Comment: Check out [GetFileAttributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364944%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: `_access` continues to return success, even with "List folder contents" permission removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to be sure if an operation will succeed is to actually try the operation.

However, `SetCurrentDirectory` will fail if you don't have `FILE_TRAVERSE` or `SYNCHRONIZE` permissions for the folder in question. So you can test this using `CreateFile` without actually changing the directory.

```
bool TestForSetCurrentDirPermission(LPCWSTR pszDir)
{
    HANDLE hDir = CreateFile(pszDir, FILE_TRAVERSE | SYNCHRONIZE,
        FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, 0, OPEN_EXISTING,
        FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS, NULL);

    if (hDir != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) CloseHandle(hDir);
    return hDir != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
}
```